# Disable autocomplete on tab

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext4

After update from sublime text 3 autocomplete triggers on `TAB` and `ENTER`

Its hard to use snippets like `foreach` in PHP

```
foreach($mark as $mark => $mark) {
    $mark
}
```

In sublime text 3 after `TAB` you jump to next mark, but now autocomplete happens

I tried some settings

```
"tab_completion": false,
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
```

Not working

Found key binding

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }]
},
```

Dont know how to remove it

Pls help, its too hard to use Sublime text now

Answer (score 2):

I tried some solutions, there are not perfect. There is a worked solution: [[SOLVED] ST3: “tab_completion”: false does not work](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-st3-tab-completion-false-does-not-work/53526),
but now I want to provide mine (inspired by this link ↑, thanks for @OdatNurd).

**1. Preferences -> Key Bindings**

**2. Search '"keys": ["tab"]' at left window**, then you get a group of result. It's look like this for me:

```
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "auto_complete", "args": {"mini": true, "default": "\t"},
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operand": false },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": ".*\\w", "match_all": true },
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "expand_snippet", "context":
        [{ "key": "has_snippet" }, ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "indent", "context":
        [{ "key": "text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\n" }]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "overlay_has_focus", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "next_field", "context":
        [{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
        [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }]
    },
```

(I don't want to imply what it should look like, because different sublime versions will have different settings.)

**3. COPY them all into the right window.**

**4. DELETE (or just Comment Out) both "auto_complete" block and "commit_completion" block at right the window, and don't change anything else.** Now, my User Keybindings like this:

```
  // Disable all autocompletion and tab completion. This overrides the default
  // binding for this key.
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"} },
  // { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "auto_complete", "args": {"mini": true, "default": "\t"},
  //   "context":
  //   [
  //     { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operand": false },
  //     { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
  //     { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
  //     { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": ".*\\w", "match_all": true },
  //   ]
  // },
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "expand_snippet", "context":
    [{ "key": "has_snippet" }, ]
  },
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "context":
    [
      { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
      { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
      { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
      { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
    ]
  },
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "indent", "context":
    [{ "key": "text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\n" }]
  },
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
      { "key": "overlay_has_focus", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
  },
  { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "next_field", "context":
    [{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }]
  },
  // { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
  //   [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }]
  // },
```

4. **Enjoy it .** This solution won't break the snippets index, and you can commit completion with `enter`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with sublime text build 4126

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `tab_completion: false`.  When I added this to my preferences, and typed some text and hit tab, it no longer pops up an auto-complete modal, and just inserts `\t` like I wanted it to.

Comment: already tried it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how portable the solution is (especially with regards to different *versions* of Sublime). I'm on Linux (Fedora 34) and using the latest Sublime from their [official repo](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html) (build 4121 at time of writing) with a registered license.

But I think the issue I had was similar to yours (your post was the first duckduckgo result for "sublime disable auto complete on tab"). Basically, I already had `auto_complete` and `auto_match_enabled` both set to `false` in my preferences file but was still seeing that if I had some text such as:

```
async:      false,
```

and I placed my cursor after the "c" in async and hit TAB that it would try to autocomplete this to some word that began with "async". But the behavior that I *wanted* was for it to literally insert a TAB (`\t`) character instead of using TAB as auto-completion trigger.

After reading this post, I tried `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false` which didn't seem to work for me either. I couldn't figure out how to override the selector keybinding so I started disabling a lot of auto-complete settings in a "shotgun approach". I did search online for settings but mostly just went off of the descriptions in the global / left-hand side of the settings file.

I'm not sure of the exact setting that did it but it now behaves as I wanted with TAB just inserting a `\t` character. I suspect that `"auto_complete_size_limit": 1` may have been the most relevant setting but I'm not sure.

Here is my preferences file for reference:

```
{
    "always_prompt_for_file_reload": true,
    "atomic_save": true,
    "auto_close_tags": true,
    "auto_complete": false,
    "auto_complete_size_limit": 1,
    "auto_complete_selector": "",
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
    "auto_complete_with_fields": false,
    "auto_complete_cycle": false,
    "auto_complete_use_index": false,
    "auto_complete_use_history": false,
    "auto_complete_trailing_symbols": false,
    "auto_complete_include_snippets": false,
    "auto_complete_include_snippets_when_typing": false,
    "auto_match_enabled": false,
    "copy_with_empty_selection": false,
    "drag_text": false,
    "detect_indentation": true,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "font_size": 15,
    "highlight_modified_tabs": true,
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "tab_completion": false,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "update_check": false,
    "close_find_after_find_all": false,
    "close_find_after_replace_all": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, in settings, it says:

// Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is enabled.

Just thought I'd post the simple workaround that exists by default, where you don't need to disable tab auto completion